# What is this electronic set up with a red light on top of it?

Tags: power-electronics

Anyone can tell me what this is ? Not sure if it exactly pertains here in the electronics forum but I think it does . What is this set up near my house and why is there a really bright red light on top of it https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg7b0.jpg more pics https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N0SC.jpg

[image]

Comment: Probably some people can think of some possibilities, but have you considered actually asking your city council?

Comment: Is it a gas detection system?

Comment: @immibus Asking a authority? That's crazy talk. I suppose you read directions before assembling things, and leave the tags on your mattresses as well! It looks like it has to big a transformer for just a gas monitoring station. But the red lights definitely mean danger. To bad the sign that says what it is can't be read. : )

Comment: Are those dwellings built on an old rubbish dump? that would explain a gas detection system...

Comment: Asking a city council things like this gets people on lists...

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a Q&A site for any kind of question about any kind of thing that has a light bulb attached to it.

Comment: @SaraHeart "But the red lights definitely mean danger." Not necessarily, around here we got underground waterpumps which have a control unit in a housing roughly like the picture with the same red lamp on top. When the lamp is on, the unit is active. No danger.

Comment: ICBM silo hatch

Comment: – @Mast I bow to your superior knowledge in this area. But I must admit my favorite answer so far is ICBM silo hatch. Put it where the commies will never suspect!

Comment: Also, *the thing probably has a sign on it, read the sign*

Answer (score 8):

Based on the concrete slabs with access doors and vent pipes around it, that's almost certainly a waste water lift station control and monitoring unit.

Lift stations are used when waste water drainage and/or local sewer lines collect at a point below the existing main sewers. They pump the water back up into the sewer system where it can be gravity fed to the water treatment facility. They are very common in fairly flat areas with a high water table (like South Florida, where the OP's pic was taken).

The red light on top can be used to indicate an active pump or alert to a failure. If the light is on for more than a few minutes, you should definitely call the numbers on the posted signs.

[image]

Brief article: ["What Are Lift Stations"](http://liftstationservices.com/?page_id=48)

Brief video: ["How a Lift Station Works"](https://youtu.be/MxnZGD2RRyc)

[Image Source and a diagram of inner workings.](https://www.allcountysepticservices.com/Lift-Station.html)

Comment: Wow your right people on this site know everything xD I was actually confused cuz I was walking home tonight and I saw the red light on and wondered what this was here's a pic of it at night https://imgur.com/a/NadglzR

Comment: @GeorgeXander Seemed like there was some light reflection on the street in that pic, suggesting it had recently rained. Chances are it was running to pump off the rain water. When in doubt though, you should call the listed numbers. If the light is a failure alarm it could be bad news for the neighbors.

Comment: Will look into it, at first I thought someone was messing with me and shining a laser at me so I got shooken up but then I looked closer and saw that it was a light in there .

Comment: There are quite a few of those near where I live in south Florida. There is usually a sign on the fence enclosure that says "If the light is on, call this number".

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Phil C's answer.
The image below suggests that you want the waste water systems in your area to be operating "really well" at all times.

The location you identified is marked by the red symbol near the centre of the the images below.

The top image is from Garglabet maps, and the bottom version emphasises why you would want your waste water "lift" stations to be able to lift as required at all times.

**"Water, Water everywhere - nor any drop to drink ..."**

[image]

Comment: And why now? On one image it seems open water is marked red, but what does that mean?

Comment: @PlasmaHH "Judgement call" :-) - In the upper image you get a feel of the area and while the water is visible it does not greatly contrast with its surrounds, so that the smaller areas (which still constitute a substantial amount of water) tend to not stand out. In the lower image I have muted down the green and hanged (most of) the various shades of blue-ish water into a single shade of highly contrasting red. I could have used just the lower image, but felt that seeing the area 'as it was in reality' added to the result. YMMV.

Comment: Never having such pump stations anywhere where I live, I must be a bit slow here, but are you saying that this much water could get into the system and it must work very well to be able to cope with it?

Comment: In Netherlands these things are abundant in low population areas. We call them something like pressure drainages. I used to work for a company that made engineering drawings for their control panels. +1 for your reference to Samual Taylor Coleridge/Iron Maiden.

Comment: @Bart An original STC reference alas :-) - I'm too old to be aware of Iron Maiden usage thereof :-) | A cafe here was named "Uber Alles". They said it was a reference to a "Dead Kennedys" title, but many people complained, having an eye to an older use of the words, and they were compelled to change the name.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Didn't mean to be confusing. Just seemed likely that if they need "lift stations" and with that much water as a % of land area then the water table is probably not too far below street level. If the lift station is showing an alarm light the water table may be following close behind. To maintain dry feet (or lawns or basements) a call to the lift station people would seem wise.

Comment: @Russell McMahon: The DK title you are referring to was California uber alles. Maiden's usage of STC's text is from 1984, pretty old already I think :)
The company we made the drawings for was Flygt Water and Wastewater Solutions. They make this typical roadside pumps.

Comment: @Bart I turned 34 in 1984 :-).

Answer (score 1):

While we are guessing, I throw out this one: Warning light for ICBM silo. If you see that thing turn on, run for cover.

It's probably a control box for a water pump, for a well, or maybe a sewage lift station. Who knows... and doesn't really matter.

I have one of these near me, mine is for a water pump.

[image]

Comment: +2 for the ICBM silo. -1 for the "doesn't really matter". See the images in my 'answer' for why it may be wise to ring someone if that light is on during rainy weather :-)